# Dynamic Update stored procedure SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, dynamic

I have a table with 30+ fields. Many of the fields allows NULL. My question is if I want to update the field(s) that changed value, how do I do that with stored procedure? Currently I am selecting a specific row and storing all the current values in the table. Next I would have to compare each variable to the new one to see if they are different, and if it is, then add that field name and the new variable to the string query. Then execute. Is there a more efficient way of doing this? As you imagine, it is a pain to compare all 30+ fields, especially since many are Nullable. Thank you.

So here is my logic so far in my stored procedure:

1. Have all the parameters that are nullable and set them to null (since it is optional).
2. DECLARE a variable for each field which I will be testing (30+ fields)
3. SELECT the row identify by the ID passed in from the parameter (primary key).
4. Store all the values into each variable.
5. Check each value to see if it IS NULL. If so, that means the user did not provide the field so no update in necessary for that field. If the parameter value IS NOT NULL, check if it is == to the value SELECTED from the database. If the value !=, then add it to the query string to be updated.
6. Execute the update query string.

Comment: Why do you need to compare the fields prior to updating?

Comment: @ChrisLively because I want to check if there was a true update with rows affected. Since I will have a table to store the old values. If rows affect > 0, I will insert all the old values in another table to keep history. So I have to check prior to updating since from my understanding, an update query will have rows affected even if the values being update is the same.

Comment: Generally speaking, tables that store the old values have all of the same columns as the original table (plus one for who initiated the change and a date/time field).  These are generally populated by triggers that occur when the update statement is run which makes it trivial to determine if a record update occurred.   I'm still not seeing why you need to compare all of the values and use dynamic sql.

Comment: But I will not know if the values truly changed unless I compare it before updating correct? I do not want to store values that have not changed since if I run an update query, rows affect will be 1 regardless if the values were same as before. Also, these rows will constantly be checked if changes were made (maybe one every 5 seconds) so if I am constantly inserting and updating values, I do not find that efficient and defeats the purpose will thousands of rows as my "old values" when they have not truly changed.

Comment: The update statement doesn't need to care about it.  In the trigger you can easily compare the old and new row states to see if a column has changed and optionally insert the new stuff into your history table.

Comment: OR I guess an alternative would be to still compare the values, but instead of having the stored procedure do that, I can write that into my code (C# Visual Studio). But this might cause an issue if whoever is using the stored procedure mess up and executes the update query EVEN if they values have not changed thus creating a new row in the 'history' table when there was no such changes. So it is best to compare it in the stored procedure to have more control?

Comment: All the more reason to use a trigger.  That way it fires and captures the update no matter how they chose to update the table.

Comment: @ChrisLively Ah I see what you mean, what would you suggest since both methods require the comparison whether in the trigger or in the stored procedure? I have read that triggers are 'evil' and so if there are not much advantages using the trigger, would manually adding the comparison to my stored procedure to insert a row in the 'history' table only if a true update was made  be better? Thank you and I apologize for my bad grammar.

Comment: @kevinyu. Checking client side relies on nothing else changing the data while you are checking. Don't go there

Comment: Triggers exist to provide exactly this type of guaranteed functionality.  When used in this context they are far from evil: they are the only true way.

Comment: But what if I am writing an Update stored procedure anyway? I assume it will be a lot neater if it updates regardless and I will have the trigger do its job to compare the old and new value to see if a new row is needed for the history table. Would this be less efficient since I am running the update stored procedure constantly regardless if the values have changed and it is still making the updates?

Comment: ALso on a side note, can I have a dynamic stored procedure that updates multiple data types? for example UpdateSP(string ColumnName, object newValue)?